# Returning data members of primitive types as a const reference?

Tags: c++

Example: I have a class named Class and it has a data members **std::string m_name** and **int m_value**.

To avoid unnecessary copies I do this.

```
const std::string& Class::name() const;
```

To make the functions consistent would it acceptable to do this for primitive types as well?

```
const int& Class::value() const;
```

Comment: What makes you think that you need to avoid unnecessary copies?

Comment: Primitives don't really have any advantage to using references, but you're probably getting RVO anyway.

Comment: @TonyTheLion: Imagine: Class c; std::cout << c.name() << std::endl; I would not like a copy here.

Comment: To be honest, I don't see why you'd even remotely think that this could even present an issue?!! What do you think the issue is if there was a copy there? (assuming there is even a copy, compilers are very good at copy elision, where appropriate)

Answer (score 0):

To the user of your API it will make no difference.
His code will look like

```
Class c;
c.value(1940);
int x = c.value();
```

whichever way you write it.

One thing that he might be able to do if you return references (which you may or may not want) is

```
const int &x = c.value();
int &k = const_cast<int &>(x);
k++; // will change the internals of your object
```

It's your choice.

Comment: Honestly, `const_cast` was put into the language for a reason. If the user goes out of their way to abuse it, it's not your problem if things stop working properly.

Comment: @chris still, the latter IS possible if you return a reference, and it will work fine. It will NOT work if you return a value! Try using that in a security-related dll API, and it's an open hole for abusers.

Comment: True, I was thinking along the lines of just a helpful class for users, not an important emphasis on security.